# Strapi database import, images are there but not mapped in CMS GUI

Tags: strapi

We are working on a strapi CMS project; first time using the CMS.

I was passed the database to import into my instance, everything imported except the images are no longer mapped correctly in CMS dashboard. They are all wonked out, all the images are in the media library, but after the import it looks like I would need to go into each page and re-map/re-point each image to the correct section. This seems ridiculous to me and would require alot of extra time. Why is this happening and how can this be fixed?